# Unable to find activity error

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-activity, android-logcat

I have been trying to go back to an activity after saving some data. The saving all works find. No errors there and all the streams are closed. Then I try to go back to the MainMenu activity and it seems not to work. Also something that I don't know if it will effect it but if I created some TextFields in the class do I need to remove them before going to a new activity?

The Code for new activity in ("com.sureclean.versionioo.settings"):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        //Saving data code in here
    startActivity(new Intent("com.sureclean.versionioo.MainMenu"));
}
```

Whole Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sureclean.versionioo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sureclean.versionioo.MainMenu" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".checklist"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".checklist" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sureclean.versionioo.settings" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

LogCat:

```
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.surehere.versionioo.MAIN }
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.sureclean.versionioo.settings$1.onClick(settings.java:54)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-12 15:58:03.949: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Actually, how many activities you have? It seems you're starting your current activity from same activity?

Comment: I am starting the "com.sureclean.versionioo.MainMenu" activity from the "com.sureclean.versionioo.Settings" Activity. But to get to settings you need to go from MainMenu, is that my problem?

Comment: `.Mainmenu` is your main Activity right? And, have you registered your `.Settings` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: No, .Spalsh is my main Activity. and what exactly do you mean by registered? The code is in the manifest.

Comment: Okay, just let me know where you're calling the `startActivity` means, that `onclick` code?

Comment: And, if you want to go back to your previous activity means, you simply use `finish()` why you're start Activity again?

Comment: Hmmm Ok I will try that... And the startActivity is done in the "com.sureclean.versionioo.Settings"

Comment: See, simply do one thing, inside of `onClick` use `finish()`

Comment: With finish() I still seem to get the same error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16575/discussion-between-spk-and-nicholas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this activity is exists in package defined in manifest ...You can write android:name=".MainMenu"

but if package name is others so write full name

android:name="yourpackagename.MainMenu"

**Use this manifest once**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sureclean.versionioo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".checklist"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**and in button onclick**

```
startActivity(new Intent(settings.this,MainMenu.class));
```

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.surehere.versionioo.MAIN } why it is this?  com.surehere.versionioo.MAIN

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. That's why I got confused! And the com.surehere.versionioo.MAIN is the splash.

Comment: Done, it is now in the question :)

Comment: You dont need to define intent filter everywhere ..its only need for main activity of ur class..it is splash so only use this for other activities  <activity
        android:name="com.sureclean.versionioo.MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>

Comment: Oh Sorry that was me just testing one of the answers, ill change it back to what it was :)

Comment: have u removed filters n checked?

Comment: yeap I have, Any other subjection guys?

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Your Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainMenu"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
</activity>
```

Your code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenu.class));
}
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? If so, this means that you have no MainMenu Activity and/or you define your activity incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error again. In error you are getting the package

> "com.**surehere**.versionioo.MAIN "

and you have define the action to your activity is

> "com.**sureclean**.versionioo.MainMenu"

Means that something is wrong in the package name. check the package name once.

Comment: The package name is "com.sureclean.versionioo" so where does that leave me?

Comment: Find out from where this package is calling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your manifest mentioned above :

```
    Intent intMainMenu=new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
    intMainMenu.setAction("com.sureclean.versionioo.MainMenu");
    startActivity(intMainMenu);
```

Comment: Sorry but new Intent(this, MainMenu.class) doesn't seem to be working for me?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.sureclean.versionioo", "com.sureclean.versionioo.MainMenu");
            startActivity(intent);
```

i encounter the same problem and this code works